# Parent restarted by child doesn't respond to CTRL-C

Tags: terminal, process, signals, process-groups

I wrote a program. It starts a process (call it A) that spawns a child process (call it D) that shutdowns and restarts A. Problem is, now I can't kill A nicely from the terminal (ie. CTRL-C isn't getting to it). The pgid's of A and D are the same, but it looks like the terminal drops that process group as its foreground, which is why I can't send it signals now. I suspect this happens when the parent process originally dies. Is there some way to prevent that? Can I change the foreground pgid so it looks like the child (D) is actually the parent and the terminal doesn't drop the process group?

Comment: The question is unclear to me. You're mixing _program_ and _process_ in a confusing way. Is it `D` that _shutdowns_? What do you mean by that?

Comment: I added a period to clarify. It's all one program. You can launch it from the terminal with `restarter -A`. It spawns a child process using exec (ie. it calls `restarter -D`). Now we have two processes, A and D. Process D now sends SIGINT to A, causing A to die. Now D runs exec `restarter -A`, effectively restarting process A. Now the terminal user can no longer kill the processes with CTRL-C

Comment: Note that `exec` doesn't spawn a process. The shell is waiting for the first process, once that dies, the shell sets the foreground process group back to the shell's. You'd need your first process not to die or be suspended. Probably better rethink the whole thing. If D is a monitoring process, it should be the parent.

Comment: is it possible to avoid giving up the foreground pg, even with a dead parent?

Comment: you could pipe your process to `cat` (`restarter -A | cat`). `cat` would not die until the pipe is closed (that is when all the processes have died (unless they close their stdout)).

Comment: or using another fd to avoid affecting stdout: `{ restarted -A 3>&1 >&4 4>&- | cat > /dev/null 4>&-; } 4>&1`

Comment: thats clever. Im trying to avoid the end user (who types restarter -A) from having to run anything else, otherwise I'd just have them start the supervisor first. But I think I figured out the solution: an extra call to exec at the beginning, and let the first process hang forever to catch the signals

Answer (score 0):

A simple enough solution:

Have process A exec a second process A first (call it A'). Then let A block forever. A' can start D, and D can restart A', and A sticks around the whole time as the parent.

Comment: You mean fork a second process (not exec). If you exec a copy of yourself, you will restart, in same process.

Comment: sorry, my language is colored by use of golang, which doesn't seem to have fork, only something exec-like